# "Button Style" vs. "Button Styles"

Tags: grammar

I'm working on an app where the user can change how a button looks (size, color, etc.) and I don't know if I should name that tab/section "Button Style" or "Button Styles".

There will also be a "Copy Button Style" or "Copy Button Styles" option.

Comment: Button Style sounds better to me.  I can give no grammatical reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a semantics question than a grammar question.

I assume that the user will be only able to use one single button style at a time — is that correct? If so, "Button Style" and "Copy Button Style" would be the correct labels to use.